# Get spanID as string when innerHTML matches a value

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

i am trying to write a Greasemonkey-Script that finds a certain string in innerHTML and gets me the spanID of that object as a string in a variable.

This is the Code on the Website:

```
<span id="spanID_Text">MatchText</span>
```

So i need to get the "spanID_Text" as a Variable when MatchText ist the correct value.

Can you please help me?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: Can you please share what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried nothing, because i really don't know how to do it.

Comment: Have you written the script to get `innerHTML` as string?

Comment: I need to get the " spanID_Text" as a Variable ? What you need to fetch content of that div.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for!

```js
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span')

for(var i= 0; i<spans.length;i++){
  if(spans[i].innerHTML.search("MatchText")>-1){
    var idMatchingSpan = spans[i].id;
    console.log(idMatchingSpan)
  }
}
```

```html
<span id="spanID_Text">This is MatchText</span>
<span id="spanID_1">NotMatching</span>
<span id="spanID_2">NotMatching</span>
<span id="spanID_3">NotMatching</span>
```

Comment: Please notice *finds a certain string in innerHTML* in the question.

Comment: @Rajesh Now looks fine!